# Sharepoint Online Public Website Forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, client-object-model

I have several forms that need to be sent to an email when filled. How do i do this to enable anonymous users to do that, It only allows authenticated users to submit the form via JSOM

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at similar question here:

[Add list item using anonymous user in public website of shareopint 2013 office 365](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a890e2ee-d615-45b1-b031-4a347e04bcf7/add-list-item-using-anonymous-user-in-public-website-of-shareopint-2013-office-365?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Most of them recommend using http://anonymous365.codeplex.com solution to select what permissions you want to give to anonymous users on the list.

Another way suggested was to use Impersonation step in a Workflow, but I can't think of a way to trigger workflow.